# Starcraft 2 not displaying map in game

Tags: video, wine, games, playonlinux

I installed Starcraft II wings of liberty via playonlinux, it installed fine, it starts up fine, but when I go into a game the map does not show, it is just black, but all my buildings/units/mineral line shows up, but everything else is black, also all the abilities do not have any graphics, and I can not see my player portrait in the menus. 
I am on a 32 bit version of ubuntu 12.04 with wine 1.5.10

I think it is probably a missing package I need to install...but I have no clue which one it would be, or if it is even that.

Can anyone help?
Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 0):

I advise You asking this question on PlayOnLinux forums. They have great community and they know better for sure.

Comment: Okay sorry, I am new to linux, so trying to get my bearings, and will switch 100% if I can just get this and a couple other things work out.